# How would a thread acquire the lock after being awaken by a mesa semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, locking, semaphore

In [this video](https://youtu.be/DaOLlnOV0s0?t=4200), there is a pseudo code for a semaphore that's used to solve the Producer–consumer problem. The producer puts items in a queue, and the consumer takes from the queue. The code looks like this:

The thread that owns the lock that is about to wake up one thread:

```
// producer

lock.acquire()     // 1
...
dataready.wakeOneThread() // 2 
... 
lock.release();    // 3
```

The thread about to be awaken up:

```
// consumer

lock.acquire()              // 1
...
while (queue.isEmpty()) {   // <------ program continues from here
    dataready.wait(lock);   // 2
}
...
lock.release();             // 3
```

The function `wakeOneThread` releases the lock, puts one thread in the ready queue, acquires the lock again, the lock is released on `line 3` (I may be wrong). After putting one thread in the ready queue, if it happens that the thread is woken up while the `producer` is still acquiring the lock, that thread (the `consumer`) should wait until the lock is released (at least they say so, that it waits until the lock is released).

My questions are:

---

1 - How is this working?

The thread will wake up, find that the queue is not empty, continues, hits the `line 3`, waits until the lock is free, acquires it, then releases it.

Is it busy waiting for the lock to be released? If not, then, since no one will wake it up again, how would it know that the lock is released?

I'm not sure if that's the case since busy waiting is not so efficient...

---

2 - Assuming that it's busy waiting, second problem, the `consumer` will continue and modify values as if it had the lock. I believe the lock should be acquired the moment it starts running...

I'm not sure whether that's the case or not (the thread acquires the lock the moment it starts) since there is no indication in the code that this happens.

When the producer hits `line 3` (after the `consumer` is awaken up and acts as if it owns the lock), the lock will be released again, and another thread would be able to acquire the lock, thus two threads thinking that they both own the lock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thread will wake up, find that the queue is not empty, continues, hits the line 3, waits until the lock is free, acquires it, then releases it.

If the queue is already non-empty, `wait` is never called and the mutex is still head during the `...` between 2 and 3. If the queue is empty, then `wait` is called, atomically releasing the mutex and waiting, then re-acquiring the mutex. Either way, the `...` between 2 and 3 is executed while holding the mutex and with the queue non-empty. So you would put the code to take an item out of the queue there.

> Is it busy waiting for the lock to be released? If not, then, since no one will wake it up again, how would it know that the lock is released?

> I'm not sure if that's the case since busy waiting is not so efficient...

That's up to the implementation to do whatever is most efficient. It may try busy waiting for very small amount of time, but it probably will just use kernel function to make the thread no longer ready-to-run.

> 2 - Assuming that it's busy waiting, second problem, the consumer will continue and modify values as if it had the lock. I believe the lock should be acquired the moment it starts running...

The consumer would do its modification in the `...` part. That's before the lock is released in step 3. So that's done with the lock held.

> When the producer hits line 3 (after the consumer is awaken up and acts as if it owns the lock), the lock will be released again, and another thread would be able to acquire the lock, thus two threads thinking that they both own the lock...

The producer does not own the lock after line 3 and does not need it. The `...` before step 2 represents putting the item on the queue (though it could be done in the `...` after step 2. The lock is held for all the code between 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In case the `consumer` holds the lock until it finishes then gives it back to the `producer`, that would be a `hoare semaphore`, am I right? 

Also, for it to be a `mesa semaphore`, I think `line 2` has to come after `line 3` in the producer code, right?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a mistake in the comments of the `consumer` code,

In this implementation specifically, the sleeping of the thread as well as reacquiring the lock happens inside the `wait` function.

The `wait` function looks something like this:

```
... wait(SpinLock* lock)
{
    ...
    release_lock(lock);
    sleep()                 // sleeps and puts the thread in the wait channel.
    acquire_lock(lock)      // <------ program continues from here
    ...
}
```

I assumed that the program will continue from the line `while (queue.isEmpty()) {` but that's wrong.

The program will actually continue from inside the `wait` function and after exiting the function, the lock will be acquired.

Here, a spin lock is used, and the thread being awaken up will busy wait until the lock is released. This shouldn't take much time since the spin lock will be busy only until the producer releases the lock, which is probably right after waking up the thread (the producer function may finish even before the thread is woken up, in this case there will be no busy waiting at all).